# URL rewriting in PHP without htaccess

Tags: php, web-hosting

Website is running on a web host where we don't have access to a `.htaccess` file. However, I want to do URL rewriting for user friendly URLs.

e.g. Original URL

```
www.example.com/file?q=name
```

expected URL

```
www.example.com/file/name
```

Comment: just take an example of
article section of website.user submits a article and dynamic url is generated like www.domain-name/articles?cat=3&id=34 but i want like this www.domain-name/articles/cat-name/article-name

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As other people said, just use links like `/index.php/nice/looking/url`.
The "index.php" in the middle of the URL might look a little strange, but I don't think it's possible to have it look better without .htaccess

Else, you could ask your hoster to redirect any URL to /index.php so that you can handle URL rewriting without having `/index.php` in your URL.

Then you can just use a regex match to detect what file to include.
`preg_match('@[/]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@', $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"], $matches)` *($matches will contain all "parts" of the url in an array)*

Be careful with including the files, use a **whitelist** so you're sure nobody would be able to load internal files.

Answer (score 5):

as Alix Axel suggested you can use

```
www.example.com/index.php/file/name
```

then you will use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to process the URL.

Comment: Better use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in this case.

Comment: This workaround looks good. one problem when i am using www.domain-name.com/index.php/filename it looks like current directory changes
and all css formating lost and relative navigation is also not working.
any suggestions.

Comment: add / base reference for your each file reference
like
`<a href="/support.html"> </a>`
also link your CSS by using base reference `src="/media/css.css"`

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet will be to have URLs such as this:

```
www.example.com/index.php/file/name
```

You'll to rewrite your PHP code though.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Apache server and [*AcceptPathInfo*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) is enabled, then you can use the URL you wrote. A request of `/file/name` will then be automatically rewritten to `/file` with the *PATH_INFO* value of `/name` if `/file` is a regular file.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible solely using language/content negotiation in the Apache configuration (httpd.conf or apache2.conf) along with rewrite rules. Use of an `.htaccess` file is not required.

In apache2.conf file (or httpd.conf) add the `Multiviews` directive, `MultiviewsMatch` directive, and **rewrite rules**:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

    <Files "*.php">
        MultiviewsMatch Any
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Then save the file and restart Apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

If you specify the `Options` directive later in httpd.conf, you have to repeat the `Multiviews` directive for each site:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/chocolate.com/>
  Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/vanilla.com/>
  Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This will not adversely affect content negotiation if you are already serving in multiple languages. For example, replacing example.com/home.php with

> home.en.php
> home.fr.php
> home.de.php

Then in apache2.conf:

```
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage de .de
AddLanguage en .en
LanguagePriority fr de en
ForceLanguagePriority Fallback
```

Your language will still be negotiated but the php extension will not appear in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

or can create a routing switch in the index.php file:

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($request) {
    case '/file' :
        require __DIR__ . '/file';
        break;
    case '' :
        require __DIR__ . '/file';
        break;
    case '/file/name' :
        require __DIR__ . '/file?q=name';
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        require __DIR__ . '/404.php';
        break;
}
```