# What meaning does the text in the URL have after index.php/

Tags: php, url, url-routing

I am wondering what special meaning does text in the URL have after index.php/
So I would have an address like www.site.com/index.php/sometext
Is it parsed as a GET parameter, or something else.

I am working on a PHP framework for my personal use. 
The problem I'm trying to solve is URL routing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839666/php-clean-url

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question about the URL parsing.

Comment: @Rasteril It does in one of the answers. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

Comment: What's the framework? Most frameworks do routing for you.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I am building my own mini framework, I kinda wanted to know the behind the scenes action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering what special meaning does text in the URL have after index.php/

There is no *intrinsic* special meaning there. Special meaning gets assigned after the first `?` and after the first `#`.

That said, the same script will be run for `/index.php` and `/index.php/foo/bar/baz`, and the full URL requested will be available via `$_SERVER`, so the script can add its own special meaning to it.

See `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` for some interesting bits. `print_r` on `$_SERVER` is also worthwhile.

Comment: Is there any way to see what the user has typed into the space, even though it has no meaning at first?

Answer (score 1):

Most frameworks use the text after `index.php` to route the request without having to rely on ugly query (ex: `?page=foo`). So removing the `index.php` with some `.htaccess` rule for instance would provide a way to have beautiful urls: `site.com/foo/bar`. The part after the `index.php` can be accessed via `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Answer (score 1):

Path after `/index.php` is available inside your `index.php` code as:

```
 $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]
```

e.g. for the URL of `http://domain.com/index.php/nice/url`:

```
$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]=/nice/url
```

This technique is used to create clean/pretty URL in PHP **without any support of .htaccess**.

Comment: So what is generally preferred: htaccess, or this method?

Comment: .htaccess is preferred way of geting pretty URL actually.