# PHP Dynamic Folders

Tags: php, dynamic, directory

Using PHP, how can you make a dynamic folder system, like http://website.com/user/UsernameHere/ show something like http://website.com/user.php?name=UsernameHere

Does this require server configuration, or is it possible with PHP?

Comment: Do you want to take a clean url (without variables) and make it a none clean url (with variables)?

Comment: I want to know how to get a clean url to function at all, so that it will be equivalent to a url with variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically this will rely on some amount of URL-rewriting support from the web server, for instance, some mod_rewrite rule under apache.

Whether or not it's a bunch of complicated rewrite rules, or just a simple one that rewrites everything to /index.php (and let's index.php parse and interpret the URI), doesn't matter.

But you'll need some amount of web server configuration to get it going.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few techniques for doing this.  It's *nearly* possible to [clean up your URLs using just PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126762/url-rewriting-in-php-without-htaccess), but ultimately if you want to get rid of the ".php" extension you'll need to do something with your server.  If it's Apache you can [clean up using the .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-url-re-writing-in-php).