# URL rewriting in PHP with access to the .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126762/url-rewriting-in-php-without-htaccess) question, someone asked if it were possible to do a certain type of url rewriting without access to the php file. (see the question for more info.) How do I too this with access to the php file?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: How can we possibly know what you are trying to do when you don't say how **you** would like the URLs to be rewritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

It just means, rewrite any requests that don't end in js, ico, txt, gif, jpg, png, or css to your index.php file. In index.php, you can access any parameters using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and parse it as needed.