# I need to format my URL using .htaccess file but my script not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my URL 
http://www.example.com/details.php?id=12&page=120.v2013-09-18.by.Acme

My htaccess script

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^details/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /details.php?id=$1&post=$2 [L]
```

I need to get my URL to 
http://www.example.com/details/12/120.v2013-09-18.by.Acme.html

how can i change my url to above format. Please help me.

Comment: Notice you have incorrect slashes before details, once without and on the right with it. @anubhava corrected it btw

Comment: @MarekLisý Thanks for your reply. but below script also not working for me..I put the .htaccess file in root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need another rule to redirect old url to pretty URL:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /details\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&post=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /detail/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^details/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ details.php?id=$1&post=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for your descriptive anwer but above code is not working for me.

Comment: Not working is never a useful comment. What full URL did you try and what error you got? Where is this htaccess located?

Answer (score 0):

Someone very smart once said, instead of giving a fish to a hungry man, it is better to teach him how to fish. So I won't give you the exact solution. However, I have few tips for you.

Start with some small and easy snippet from a tutorial, that definitely works. If you can make it work on your server, then you can modify it step by step to your desired form.

If you cannot make it work, make sure, you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server. You can google easily how to do that. However, some hostings might not allow you to do this at all.

It is actually possible to have cool URL even without .htaccess and mod_rewrite. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126762/url-rewriting-in-php-without-htaccess) out.

Know that there are some already prepared solutions for cool urls, most PHP frameworks has them. Actually, doing any web page without any framework is a pain in the ass. You can try e.g. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) (seems to be the most popular one nowadays). I am using [Nette](http://www.nette.org) and I would never ever do webpage without it again.